# Privileges, Register as Version commands are greyed out when right-clicking a feature class in an ArcSDE geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase

When right-clicking a feature class in an ArcSDE geodatabase from ArcGIS Desktop, the 'Privileges', ‘Register As Version’ commands are grayed out even though the user is connected as the data owner, and (Advanced) ArcGIS Desktop license is being used.

[image]

In my case the data owner is the ‘SDE’ user, I restored this database from the backup to a new SQL server instance on a test machine, The SDE user is able to connect to the database and view the feature classes, now I am trying to assign privileges to users and register the feature classes as versioned and I found out that the Privileges, Register as Version commands are greyed!

I made sure that I am using the SDE user who owns the data and an Advanced license of ArcMAP 10.5.0 https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009946

I tried to use change privileges (data management) tool but I got this error!

ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
DBMS table not found [42000:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot find the object 'CanLocations_evw', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.]
Failed to execute (ChangePrivileges).

I checked the view in the database in its there!
What might be the issue here!

Comment: 1) The 'sde' user should never, **ever** own any spatial data, period. 2) You cannot change database name during a backup/restore import. 3) Users created during import will have different ids than in the database from which they were exported, and therefore have no privileges -- search on "sp_change_users_login"

Comment: Thanks Vince for the helpful notes you provided    1)I hate using the SDE user but this database was already there and I need to deal with it, The whole SDE things brings me problems that I never faced with the DBO user, I have a plan to Create new DB and copy the data to it in order to change from SDE to DBO schema. 2) I didn't / and will not change the database name during restore 3) I have Re-synched SQL Server logins  after restoring  the database from the  backup and everything looked good!.

Comment: Using DBO is much the same, ignoring a security model for "simplicity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will the answer is here, provided by Asrujit SenGupta

https://community.esri.com/thread/211790-privileges-register-as-version-commands-are-greyed-out-when-right-clicking-a-feature-class-in-an-arcsde-geodatabase

so mainly the issue happen because I  granted the SYSADMIN server role to the SDE login, After removing the sysadmin role everything back to normal.